# Showing Continuity: Point-Set Topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $f:X \to Y$ is continuous given that {$A_{\alpha}$} (each being closed) is a collection of subsets of $X$ and this collection is finite. We suppose further that $X= \cup_{\alpha} \ A_{\alpha}$ and $f|A_{\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$.

Idea: I would like to try and use the ["pasting lemma"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) and the fact that "such a map is continuous if $X$ can be expressed as a union of open subsets $U_{\alpha}$ such that $f|U_{\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$."

Sketch: Suppose $f$ is defined as above and $f|A_{\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$. Then by the pasting lemma $f|\cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

If $C \subset Y $ is closed , then $$ f^{-1}(C) = \cup_{\alpha} (A_{\alpha} \cap f^{-1}_{|A_{\alpha}}(C) ) $$ but $A_{\alpha} \cap f^{-1}_{|A_{\alpha}}(C) $ is closed in $A_{\alpha}$, so is closed in $X$.

The $A_{\alpha}$ are finite and so $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$

$\Rightarrow $ $f$ is continous

Comment: Oh, this is almost the same proof as open set in the image is open in the preimage.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for every $C\subset Y$ closed the set
$f^{-1}(C)\subset X$ is also closed.

Assume that $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n=X$.

Let $C\subset Y$ closed. Then 
$$
f^{-1}(C)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(C)\cap A_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \big(f|_{A_i}\big)^{-1}(C)
$$
which is closed as a finite union of closed sets.